# How to use each character in a string to represent the outcome for each integer in a list?

Tags: python, list

In python, I have a string like this: AABBAA. The string is always 6 characters. I also have a list of integers like: [2,5,4,6,0,9]. They are always a single integer (0-9) and is always 6 integers (to match the string). The char 'A' represents using the list, A_List, and for the number that matches it (in terms of index) in the integer list, it uses that number to index the A_List. Same for the char 'B'. So, in the example above you would get:

- A_List[2]
- A_List[5]
- B_List[4]
- B_List[6]
- A_List[0]
- A_List[9]

I have tried making a dictionary that has the keys: A and B and fills in the numbers as values that match, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to map your input lists to easily accessible identifiers. One way is to use a dictionary. Then use a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
d = {'A': list(range(10)),
     'B': list(range(10, 20))}

lists = 'AABBAA'
keys = [2,5,4,6,0,9]

res = [d[lst][key] for lst, key in zip(lists, keys)]

print(res)

[2, 5, 14, 16, 0, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a dictionary where the keys are the different letters in the string, in our case we would have the keys `"A"` and `"B"` which would both have the list they represent as their values.

```
mappings = {"A":A_List, "B":B_List}
```

To get the correct values from the lists we then need to loop through both the string to find out which list we're using and the list of integers to find the indexes. This can be done easily by simply using a `for i in range()` giving the length of the list as the size of the range.

```
indexes = [2, 5, 14, 16, 0, 9]
word = "AABBAA"

for i in range(len(indexes)):
    value = mappings[word[i]][indexes[i]]
    #Do whatever you want with the value here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookup contains your lists, find the target list from lookup and then use the index to find the value in the target list.

```
list_names = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A']
list_indexes = [2, 5, 4, 6, 0, 9]
lists_lookup = {
    'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'B': [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
}

result = []
for i in range(0, len(list_names)):
    target_list = lists_lookup[list_names[i]]
    index = list_indexes[i]
    result.append(target_list[index])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
newlist = []
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i] == 'A':
        newlist.append(A_list[i])
    else:
        newlist.append(B_list[i])
```

This way you don't have to worry about how long it will be, and you can map your values of the different lists under A_list and B_list.